# Use setInterval and recurcive setTimeout in SPA React application without memory leaks

Tags: javascript, reactjs, memory-leaks, garbage-collection, single-page-application

I'm using React class components. The component polls the server every 10 seconds. If data from server are different, I'm rerendering the whole tree. Some of child are pure components, some of them have my own shouldComponentUpdate.
I've used setInterval for this case. But not sure it is a good idea.
Will the variables(used in the body of setInterval) be cleared by Garbage collector?

I've tried to use recursive setTimeout. I've simplified child components and written as a book says. Here some pseudo example.

```
componentDidMount() {
  this._setInterval()
}
// ... clear timeout on willUnmount
_setInterval() {
  clearTimeout(this._timeoutId)
  this._timeoutId = setTimeout(this._pollServer, 10000)
}
_pollServer() {
  // ... fetching the data
  this._setInterval();
}
```

This is SPA, so React will call very raraely componentWillUnmount and clearInterval in it.

So what is the best solution in this case?

Comment: `setTimeout` and `setInterval` are not the same. You are not using `setInterval` anywhere.

Comment: did you consider an Observer/Obeservable solution ?

Comment: @Greedo, nope. But I will

Comment: @JavaScript I know. This is one of the solutions. And the question is what better to use and how to prevent memory leaks in SPA??? Does recursive time interval better than setInterval in this case? And do we have any other solution for this case

Answer (score 0):

One pattern that's followed by lot of Third party libraries, is create a component which just fetches data and that component should be your top component, and the data can be state of the component. You can run the interval only in that component. So when server data changes the component will rerender and so as it's child component. You can pass the data as part of props to chile component.

```html
<DataProvider><TopUIComponent data={data}></TopUIComponent></DataProvider>
```

Comment: Thanks. I'm using such a component like DataProvider. Just did not mention it in my question and example. But setTimeout is above this component, not inside. So I will consider the way how to move it into this component.

Comment: @youngB better to have single component syncing server data to client, so that it will be efficient and manageble